# PHP number_format not working in Maatwebsite Excel export package

Tags: php, export-to-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I have value in database (MySQL) **1.00**. Field type is float(10,2). I am using `Maatwebsite` Laravel package to export the data. All the values seems to be exporting correctly except the Float values.

Also if the value is **1.20** it exporting as **1.2** in the excel.

```
$productPerUnit = 1.20;
<td style=" background-color:white;text-align:center;border-right:1px solid #000000;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;">{{ number_format($productPerUnit,2) }}</td>
```

[image: Format Value after export]

If the question is duplicate I am happy to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;

Change the cell number format using this -

`$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00');`

[Github code](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Style/NumberFormat.php)
[Column formatting example](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html)

Comment: I have to change the package in order to do apply that solution. I will try the solution if i have to change the package in future. Thanks